# Vuforia / Unity: how to access augmented Image

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

here is a tricky question I am working on since days:

- Vuforia 6 / Unity 5.3.4
- I have an `ImageTarget` with a `RawImage` under it in the hierarchy
- I can detect what trackables have been tracked
- I need changing its texture / color **once it has been augmented**
- the issue I face is to find the augmented `RawImage`, starting from the active trackable:

  - I tried finding all RawImages via script - no success
  - I tried finding the GameObjects children of the Trackable transform - only if I add the children via script, then I can find them this way | I cannot find the ones already in the hierarchy
  - I tried to keep referenced to the RawImages added at runtimes to the Trackables: with these, still, I cannot affect the augmented one

???

Any clues?

Comment: can you explain your problem more & tell me what exactly you want to do?

Comment: What I am in need of doing is changing the transparency of the augmented RwImage object; I can do that when the RawImage objects are on Unity Hierarchy. I load the datasets / images at runtime and I can get the RawImage objects visible on the wanted markers. The problem is that could not find a way to reference the augmented RawImage to operate on it in scripting. Hope this helps clarify.